# Data grid does not show scroll bar and design become obsolete after adding material design in WPF MVVM Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, material-design

I am using both material design and dragablz:TabablzControl in WPF MVVM application.Material design is used to style button and text box. Grid is located inside tab control.After loading bulk data in to data grid I am facing below design issues.

- it does not show scroll bar. I have tried with scroll viewer though
  it didn't work. Actually I can scroll down using arrow key and mouse
  scroll. But the scroll bar is not visible.
- When we click on a single row of the data grid that row become invisible or fades.
- When we click on grid header it selects all the rows
- A dotted line are displayed in window.

Any way to fix issue. How can I get ride of material design only for data grid.

**XAML Sample**

```
   <Grid>
        <dragablz:TabablzControl SelectedIndex="0"  >
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                <dragablz:InterTabController/>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
            <TabItem Header="File System" >
                <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">

                        </ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="ISPAC">
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*">

                                </ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="27"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGrid Name="dataGridCustomer" Height="Auto" 
    Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"                                                                            
                                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                              DataContext="{Binding tfs}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Path=CustomerList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                              >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                                            Binding=" 
    {Binding Path=NameOfFile}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Get ">
                                        
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Content="{Binding 
     Path=Insert}"                                                           
                                                           Command= " 
     {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.InsertCommand}"
                                                           
   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    Mode=Self},Path=DataContext}"></Button>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Component" 
   Visibility="Hidden"
                                                            Binding=" 
         {Binding Path=Component,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        
                        </Grid>

                    </GroupBox>
                  
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
    </Grid>
```

**Grid UI sample**
[image]

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="BIExtractionUtilityTool.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BIExtractionUtilityTool"
          xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
         StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- primary color -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- include your primary palette -->
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!--
                        include three hues from the primary palette (and the associated forecolours).
                        Do not rename, keep in sequence; light to dark.
                    -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary700}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary700Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- secondary colour -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- include your secondary pallette -->
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- include a single secondary accent color (and the associated forecolour) -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent200}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent200Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- Include the Dragablz Material Design style -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dragablz;component/Themes/materialdesign.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- tell Dragablz tab control to use the Material Design theme -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: You've not stated how you have applied the material design theme - how did you go about this? It's not something that comes out-of-the-box with WPF application templates as far as I know - are you using this http://materialdesigninxaml.net/ ?

Comment: Material Desing doesn't remove scroll bars or change the behaviour of the `DataGrid` in the way you have described. You did this yourself somehow. Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you out.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details @Charleh . thank you very much for response

Comment: Updated the answer with more details. thank you very much @mm8

Comment: AS @Charleh said, it would help if you post the relevant part of your App.xaml, it is not clear if MaterialDesignInXAML works correctly in the rest of your windows or if you just added it

Comment: Adde App.xaml @CorradoBarbero

Comment: @mm8 can you please have look after update.

Comment: @BionicCode can you answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you are not able to see certain controls or experience odd appearance, like weird color fades, is because of the control coloring.

The Material Design themes are based or composed of several resources. This enables flexibility to customize the final theme.
You basically have control design themes and color themes that you can combine.

But you always need to import the appropriate resources, a combination of design and color theme.
`MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml` contains basic or shared theme resources that are primarily design and not color related e.g. default styles for controls. You successfully merged this resource.
But you missed to merge a color theme into your `ResourceDictionary`.

For e.g, a dark base theme you need to import `MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />

  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Alternatively you can consolidate the color themes using a `BundledTheme`, which allows to merge relevant color schemes by setting relevant attributes like primary accent color in a single `BundledTheme` object:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />

  <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Dark" 
                               PrimaryColor="Yellow" 
                               SecondaryColor="Red" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I recommend the [documentation](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started) resources on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much @BionicCode. The scroll bar issue is resolved. Excellent solution

Comment: Still that dotted line is present any idea about that. is it because of `dragablz:TabablzControl` ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell where the dashed line comes from. I see a second one next to the `Search` label. I couldn't find this label in your posted code, which seems to be incomplete. Try to display the `DataGrid` and labels without this `TabablzControl` control to see if the lines are gone.

Comment: Yes @BionicCode . It seems the issue is because of `TablzControl` . After removing `TablzControl` the dotted lines are disappeared

Comment: I am not familiar with the `TablzControl`. I don't think this is normal behavior. You should check what properties you can set to configure the control. Maybe consult the documentation.