# Unable to get values from pop up window in parent view model WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to access property value of a child window's view model from the parent View Model.I am calling window from parent view model.I want to make changes in main window based on the operation in child view model. I couldn't get any value of child view model in parent view model.I am trying this in MVVM pattern.

**Interface for dialog**

```
 public interface IWindowService
{
    void OpenDialogWindow(DialogViewModel vm);
     
}
```

**Parent view model**

```
 public class FunctionalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
private readonly IWindowService _windowService;
 private string connectionString;

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return connectionString; }
            set
            {
                connectionString = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ConnectionString"));
            }
        }
 public FunctionalViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
        {
           BuildConnectionCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(BuildConnectionString));
            _windowService = windowService;
        }
   private void BuildConnectionString(object obj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("will open a window");
            _windowService.OpenDialogWindow(new DialogViewModel());                                  

        }
}
```

**Child View Model**

```
public class DialogViewModel : FunctionalViewModel,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string textboxsaf;

        public string Textboxsaf
        {
            get { return textboxsaf; }
            set {
                textboxsaf = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Textboxsaf"));
            }
        }

        private ICommand connectionCommand;

        public ICommand ConnectionCommand
        {
            get { return connectionCommand; }
            set { connectionCommand = value; }

        }
        public DialogViewModel()
        {
            
            ConnectionCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(SetValue));
            

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public void SetValue(object test)
        {
            textboxsaf= "ValueFromPopUpWindo";           
            Application.Current.Windows[1].Close();
            
        }
     

        }
```

**ChildWindow.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="my popup window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="73,121,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=Textboxsaf,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="109,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
                 Command="{Binding Path=ConnectionCommand }"
                 />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
 <Button Name="btnConnectionString" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Connection string" Height="40" Width="150"
                                 Command="{Binding Path=BuildConnectionCommand}"
                                        DataContext="{Binding tfs}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind file of main window
MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel()
            {
                rel = new ReleaseViewModel(),
                tfs =  new FunctionalViewModel(new WindowService()),
                wnd = new DialogViewModel()
            };

        }

  
    }
    public class WindowService : IWindowService
    {
        public void OpenDialogWindow(DialogViewModel vm)
        {
            ConnectionWindow win = new ConnectionWindow();
            win.DataContext = vm;            
            win.Show();            
        }               
    }
```

**Question**

I would like to access the value of the property **Textboxsaf** in the child view model(DialogViewModel) from parent view model(FunctionalViewModel) . Assign value of **Textboxsaf** to **ConnectionString** from the funcitonalviewModel . after closing window is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `PropertyChanged` to retrieve the value of `DialogViewModel.Textboxsaf` as this proprty might change multiple times during the lifetime of the dialog.

I would make `IWindowService.OpenDialogWindow` return a custom `DialogResult` object or the original `DialogViewModel` probably converting the `IWindowService.OpenDialogWindow` to an asynchronous method.

Alternatively implement a `IWindowService.DialogClosed` event:

**FunctionalViewModel.cs**

```
public class FunctionalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IWindowService _windowService;
    private string connectionString;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return connectionString; }
        set
        {
            connectionString = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.ConnectionString)));
        }
    }

    private void BuildConnectionString(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("will open a window");
        _windowService.DialogClosed += OnDialogClosed;
        _windowService.OpenDialogWindow(new DialogViewModel());                                  
    }

    private void OnDialogClosed(object sender,  DialogResultEventArgs e)
    {
        _windowService.DialogClosed -= OnDialogClosed;
        ConnectionString = e.Result.Textboxsaf;
    }
}
```

**WindowService.cs**

```
public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public event EventHandler<DialogResultEventArgs> DialogClosed;
    public void OpenDialogWindow(DialogViewModel vm)
    {
        ConnectionWindow win = new ConnectionWindow();
        win.DataContext = vm;
        win.Closed += OnConnectionWindowClosed;
        win.Show();            
    } 
          
    protected virtual void OnConnectionWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = sender as FrameworkElement;
        this.DialogClosed?.Invoke(this, new DialogResultEventArgs(dialog.DataContext as DialogViewModel));
    }               
}
```

**DialogResultEventArgs.cs**

```
public class DialogResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DialogViewModel Result { get; }
          
    public DialogResultEventArgs(DialogViewModel result) => this.Result = result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BionicCode . generic answer .Great help

Comment: I am facing an  error "Result does not exist in current context". I think I have placed DialogResultEventArgs.cs in wrong location. where we define DialogResultEventArgs class ? @BionicCode

Comment: You can put the class anywhere. You have to add a `using` import if it's defined in a different namespace as where you use it. Where do you get this error, in `OnDialogClosed`? And where have you put the file, same assembly, different namespace?

Comment: I defined DialogResultEventArgs class in view model library . declaring public DialogResultEventArgs(DialogViewModel result) => this.Result = result; getting an error is  "must declare body because it is not marked as abstract, extern or partial" @BionicCode

Comment: @sagartech This syntax is an [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#constructors) constructor, available from C# 7.0. Seems you are using a version < C# 7.0. Simply remove the arrow and add a method body: `public DialogResultEventArgs(DialogViewModel result) { this.Result = result;  }`. This should compile now.

Comment: What about 'Eventhandler' and 'FrameWorkElement' I am getting an assembly reference error. @BionicCode

Comment: You mispelled it? It must be `EventHandler` and `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: No sorry, a typo in my code. I have fixed it.. Sorry!

Comment: Does it compile now?

Comment: Yes thank you so much @BionicCode. now I can compile. Great help

Comment: I am glad I could help. Let me know if you have more issues...

Comment: The compilation is successful. But when i change connectionString property value it doesn't hit or call OnDialogClosed method.After closing window also onDialogClosed doesn't hit.

Comment: `OnDialogClosed` is supposed to be invoked only when the `ConnectionWindow.Closed` event was raised. Does `ConnectionWindow` have a closed event? I just assumed it is a `Window`. When this window is closed by the user or programmatically, then `WindowService.OnConnectionWindowClosed` should be invoked. Does this happen?

Comment: This is a very very simple flow. It must be a very easy to spot the simple error, so don't worry. It is essential that `ConnectionWindow` has a `Closed` event and that this event is raised when `ConnectionWindow` was closed. 
If WindowService.OnConnectionWindowClosed is not called, then check if ConnectionWindow.Closed is called.

Comment: I am new to wpf MVVM. Let me try again

Comment: Let me try again. Yes connectionWindow is a window. Initialy I included `closed` event .But when I call closed event I can't relaunch the window because it will throw error window is closed. Now I am closing by setting window.visibility to hidden. @BionicCode

Comment: Ahh, see? No `Closed` event, no `DialogClosed` event. You don't need to reuse the window. Just close it. But if reusing the instance works for you, then when setting the `Visibility` to `Hidden` just call `OnClosed(EventArgs.Empty);` inside `ConnectionWindow`. This will just raise the `Window.Closed` event without actually closing the window. This should be the final fix. Didn't knew that you are reusing the `ConnectionWindow` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much again.It is a perfect fix.

Comment: @BionicCode . Can you plz have look at this issue . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555439/data-grid-does-not-show-scroll-bar-and-design-become-obsolete-after-adding-mater?noredirect=1#comment110645933_62555439

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a reference to the `DialogViewModel` and subscribe to its `PropertyChanged` event:

```
private void BuildConnectionString(object obj)
{
    var childViewModel = new DialogViewModel();
    childViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnChildPropertyChanged;
    MessageBox.Show("will open a window");
    _windowService.OpenDialogWindow(childViewModel);
}

private void OnChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(DialogViewModel.Textboxsaf))
    {
        childViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnChildPropertyChanged;
        ConnectionString = (sender as DialogViewModel)?.DialogViewModel;
    }
}
```